# While running an application on Rails, which file of our application is executed first of all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Please answer for this. The first file executed of the application while giving `rails s`.

I need to know the initiation of the application project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The flow of application run on Rails is found here.**

..]$ `rails s`

Background process

{

```
    ..config/boot.rb

    installing the file Gemfile (in root dir of appilcation)

    ..config/application.rb
```

}

**[Server boots here/ shown in Terminal]**

```
=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000

=> Call with -d to detach

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Background process

{

```
..config.ru

..config/environment.rb

..config/environment/development.rb

..config/initializer/*.*

..config/routes.rb
```

}

**[Server Starts from here/ shown in Terminal]**

```
> INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
> INFO  ruby 1.9.3 ('Date') [i686-linux]
> INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3031 port=3000
```

Answer (score 2):

The first **application** file executed will typically be `config/boot.rb`

Then `config/environment.rb`, which will typically load one of the files in `config/environments/` (which file is run, will depend on the environment that's been set.

Then `config/application.rb` will get executed

Thereafter, `config/routes.rb` will give the server its key information about how to handle incoming requests

Answer (score 0):

Type `which rails` will give you the answer.

Then open the file, which is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

Comment: This is really useful. Thank you. but i need to know the initiation of the application project.